# Replacing only a part of strings that start with certain characters in bash

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed

Am not quite familiar with bash coding. I have a cpp file

```
#include <lib1.h>
#include <ccLib1.h>
#include <anotherlib.h>
#include <ccToto.h>
```

How to make a script that would automatically replace  `<cc*.h>` with `"*.h"`; replacing only those that start with `cc`?

I tried something like `sed -i -e 's/cc*>/"/g' file.cpp`

Comment: `sed` behaves the same way invoked from any shell, or with no shell at all; moreover, it's a tool provided by your operating system, not your shell. There's nothing bash-specific here.

Comment: We have some answers already , only the specification is a bit late - not unusual in practice ;-) could you provide some further details. 1) shall the transforms leave the angle brackets intact? (I think yes not quotes instead) 2) Shall `<cc.h>`be left as is (I think yes, otherwise invalid).

Comment: @Dilettant, the OP clarified the transform to quotes on a comment to Cyrus's answer. Quotes have a distinct semantic meaning in C preprocessor syntax, and it's one that makes sense in this context.

Comment: That is why I edited the question for making this explicit, it is in the review queue ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^#include/{s/<cc\(.*\.h\)>/"\1"/;}' file
```

Output:

```
#include <lib1.h>
#include "Lib1.h"
#include <anotherlib.h>
#include "Toto.h"
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: but <*> also need to be replaced with "*"

Comment: @polar, it should be doing that replacement now (as-edited), unless you want to do that even in things that don't start with `cc` -- if that's the case, the question could stand to be edited to be made more clear.

Comment: As it stands currently, on my sed it bails out with `sed: 1: "/^#include/{s/<cc\(.*\. ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`...

Comment: @Dilettant Try adding a tactical semicolon inside the braces. `/^#include/{;s/.../.../;}` ... though syntactically, the braces are completely superfluous here.

Comment: @Dilettant: I've added a `;`. Thank you tripleee.

Comment: @tripleee thanks. On my machine `sed '/^#include/{;s/<cc\(.*\.h\)>/"\1"/;}'  file.cpp`now works. I know why I edit these sed oneliners only time boxed ... and with the help of my friends (8) ...

Comment: So just to make it explicit, the expression could be simplified to `sed '/^#include/s/<cc\([^<>]*\.h\)>/"\1"/' file` -- note also the slightly improved wildcard to avoid straddling a broket boundary (unlikely in well-formed C but why take chances).

Comment: but it worked for me only after adding -i -e: `sed -e -i ...`

Comment: @Cyrus Also please how to deal with slash (/) with sed?

Comment: @polar: If you want to search `/` escape it: `\/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^#include\ \(<cc\|<\)\(.*\)\.h>/#include "\2\.h"/g' so_file.cpp
```

Comment: Well, hm `\2` not defined in the RE is what the sed on my machine tells me when I try that answer. My eyes see the 2nd pair of parentheses, but ... the machine does not.

Comment: @Dilettant, sorry, I missed some escape character. I have revised it.

Comment: No error, good, ... but now it does not change anything i.e. `<ccLib1.h>` and `<ccToto.h>` from sample data are simply passed as they are.

Comment: @Dilettant, on my pc, <ccLib1.h> will be converted to "Lib1.h".

Comment: That is why I ony approach these sed/pattern tasks time boxed, so that I have time left to use python or the like in case I need portability ;-) Thanks for the re-tests and edits.

Answer (score 0):

For complete solutions of the amended / updated question cf. the answer of @Cyrus on this page together with the comments for eventual portability tricks. It additionally

1. anchors the stream edit expression on `^#include` and
2. transforms from `<...>` to `"..."`in the matching cases.

A simple context free solution without the later explicated transform to a different search path includes (from `<ccHeader,h>` to `"Header.h"`)

```
$> sed  's/<cc\(..*\.h>\)/<\1/g' so_file.cpp

#include <lib1.h>
#include <Lib1.h>
#include <anotherlib.h>
#include <Toto.h>
```

sed does on my machines not like the notion of at least one any character via `.+` so I simply give it `..*` without discussing further ;-)

You will want at least a character for the basename of the header, so a cc.h would be left intact.

Comment: OP says they want `"*.h"` in output. The literal quotes are probably a legitimate part of that (meaning the headers are expected to be in the source directory, not in the standard-include search path). Thus, it would be `#include "Lib1.h"`

Comment: As usual spec is far behind implementation - I asked in comment to question. In the case you suggest to also consider, There would be additional info in question helpful and needed. As it stands I think this answer is as good as it gets ... when I suggest sed patterns ;-)